# Can I use HTML5 fileSystem api in chrome extension to read/write file on user profile directory?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can I use HTML5 fileSystem api in chrome extension to read/write file on user profile directory?

I know we can't use chrome fileSystem api for read/write in chrome extension though it can be done in chrome app. But is there any way to read/write file from chrome extension on user profile directory?

Comment: Yes. For example https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem

Comment: TL;DR = No, you cannot.